# Как из data-* создать всплывающее сообщение при клике на иконку?

Tags: javascript, css3, dom

При такой структуре html, можно ли сделать всплывающую подсказку из атрибута data-*
Начал было делать, но дальше не знаю как.

```js
var NodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".text-el");
for (var i = 0; i < NodeList.length; ++i) {
  var el = NodeList[i];
}
var createToolTip = function() {
  var newEl = document.createElement('i');
  el.appendChild(newEl);
  newEl.className = "prop";

  newEl.addEventListener('click', function() {

    if (el.textContent === "Страна производителя") {
      newEl.setAttribute("data-about", "Страна регистрации торговой марки.");
      var getAttr = newEl.getAttribute("data-about");
      newEl.innerHTML = getAttr;
    }
  })
}();
```

```css
.prop::after {
  content: url("https://image.ibb.co/i4Szbe/Screenshot_19.jpg");
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
  top: 6px;
  cursor: help;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th><span class="text-el">Страна производителя</span></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Она должна при клике появляться или при наведении? Или достаточно просто подсказки на css? http://htmlbook.ru/blog/vsplyvayushchaya-podskazka-na-css

Comment: при клике с помощью JS

Answer (score 2):

Не вижу смысла назначать пользовательский атрибут, если его значение постоянно и извлекается сразу после создания. Поэтому, в данном случае, лучше сразу задавать его в разметке:

```js
function fStopProp(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}
document.querySelector('.title-row').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.className == 'text-el') {
    e.target.addEventListener('click', fStopProp);
    let oTooltip = document.createElement('SPAN');
    oTooltip.className = 'tooltip';
    oTooltip.innerHTML = `
      ${e.target.dataset['about']}
      <span onclick="
      this.parentElement.parentElement.removeEventListener('click', fStopProp);
      this.parentElement.remove();
      ">×</span>
    `;
    e.target.appendChild(oTooltip);
  }
});
```

```css
.text-el {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 1.7em 0 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.text-el::after {
  content: url('https://image.ibb.co/i4Szbe/Screenshot_19.jpg');
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  cursor: help;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px 1.1em;
  font: 0.8em 'Arial';
  border: 1px solid #ffbf00;
  border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  background: #fcf5cf;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px -5px black;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.tooltip::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -9px;
  right: 2px;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffbf00;
  border-left: 1px solid #ffbf00;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fcf5cf 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%);
}

.tooltip>span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0.4em;
  font: 1.2em 'Arial';
  color: #faa;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="title-row">
      <th><span class="text-el" data-about="Страна регистрации торговой марки.">Страна производителя</span></th>
      <th><span class="text-el" data-about="Год, месяц, день и время производства.">Дата изготовления</span></th>
      <th><span class="text-el" data-about="Порядковый номер версии.">Модификация</span></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Если же предполагается динамическое изменение описаний, то и вовсе будет лучше перенести их в объект типа массива:

```js
var oDescriptions = {
  'Страна производителя': 'Страна регистрации торговой марки.',
  'Дата изготовления': 'Год, месяц, день и время производства.',
  'Модификация': 'Порядковый номер версии.'
};

function fStopProp(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}
document.querySelector('.title-row').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.className == 'text-el') {
    e.target.addEventListener('click', fStopProp);
    let oTooltip = document.createElement('SPAN');
    oTooltip.className = 'tooltip';
    oTooltip.innerHTML = `
      ${oDescriptions[e.target.textContent]}
      <span onclick="
      this.parentElement.parentElement.removeEventListener('click', fStopProp);
      this.parentElement.remove();
      ">×</span>
    `;
    e.target.appendChild(oTooltip);
  }
});
```

```css
.text-el {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 1.7em 0 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.text-el::after {
  content: url('https://image.ibb.co/i4Szbe/Screenshot_19.jpg');
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  cursor: help;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px 1.1em;
  font: 0.8em 'Arial';
  border: 1px solid #ffbf00;
  border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  background: #fcf5cf;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px -5px black;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.tooltip::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -9px;
  right: 2px;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffbf00;
  border-left: 1px solid #ffbf00;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fcf5cf 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%);
}

.tooltip>span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0.4em;
  font: 1.2em 'Arial';
  color: #faa;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="title-row">
      <th><span class="text-el">Страна производителя</span></th>
      <th><span class="text-el">Дата изготовления</span></th>
      <th><span class="text-el">Модификация</span></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: классный ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вы хотите что-то типа такого?

```js
var NodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".text-el");
for (var i = 0; i < NodeList.length; ++i) {
  var el = NodeList[i];
}
var createToolTip = function() {
  var newEl = document.createElement('div');
  newEl.className = "prop";
  el.appendChild(newEl);
  newEl.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var help = document.createElement('div');
    help.textContent="Страна регистрации торговой марки."
    help.className = "help";
    this.parentNode.appendChild(help);
  })
 }();
```

```css
.prop {
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/i4Szbe/Screenshot_19.jpg);
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
  top: 6px;
  cursor: help;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.help {
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:0.8em;
  position:relative;
  left:10px;
  bottom:8px;
  background-color:#FFF8DC;
  border: 1px solid #DEB887;
  padding:3px;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th><div class="text-el">Страна производителя</div> </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: да, типа этого. Только с извлечением текста-подсказки из атрибута data-* и с крестиком закрыть на подсказке.

Comment: Ну я думаю вы сможете уже добавить то что вам нужно ;)